# Open JDK doesn't run my jar files

Tags: java, executable, jdk

I decided to start java programming on Linux instead of Windows, but I can only open my projects in the NetBeans IDE. When I make the distribution into a .jar file, I can't open them. I already gave it the permission to be an executable file, but when I select Open JDK jre (either 6 or 7), it just stays there. It doesn't do anything and I don't see why it happens. Any help on what to do to proceed?

PS: The program I'm trying to open has a GUI and when I run it in NetBeans it directly loads into the GUI, instead of doing something at the console

Comment: Try the following `jar tvvf <myjar.jar>` if the correct files are there (hint a JAR is just a zip file), then try `java -jar <myjar.jar>` and see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

With the amount of information you have provided I can give you only two suggestions:

1. Make sure that you have exported the JAR file correctly - it needs to be exported as a runnable JAR & have a main class specified in the Manifest
2. Try running it via "java -jar test.jar"

Comment: Got it exported that way, I run it at the Terminal and it says that the main class is not found. Guess that's the reason it doesn't open.

Comment: Does the Manifest.MF file specify which is the main class in your JAR? Should be something like "Main-Class: classname". 

If this doesn't work - upload & share your JAR file so we can take a look.

Comment: I have it specified, but it doesn't seem to work. The file says Main-Class: inventario.cosparty.InventarioCosparty, where inventario.cosparty is the package.

Comment: Edit: This is the Manifest inside the .jar:Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.9.1
Created-By: 1.7.0_45-b18 (Oracle Corporation)
Class-Path: 
Main-Class: inventario.cosparty.InventarioCosparty

Comment: I cannot provide any more ideas without the JAR itself or more info.

Comment: Here you have it: https://mega.co.nz/#!t0tCGTxY!Gq2HJis8Q7iuJPC58nAEvy6b3g5QefmVFLstByLGFtA

Comment: Runs on my machine .. "java -jar Invertario_Cosparty.jar"